# Format specifier in variable?

Tags: c

I have these variables:

```
char* name = "bobsux";    
int score = 100;
char* scoreHash = "f899139df5e1059396431415e770c6dd";
```

Printing these using format specifiers and printf, returns this:

```
printf("name=%s&score=%d&score_hash=%s", name, score, scoreHash);
=> name=bobsux&score=100&score_hash=f899139df5e1059396431415e770c6dd
```

How can I make a variable that returns the same? Failed attempt:

```
char* scoreData = ("name=%s&score=%d&score_hash=%s", name, score, scoreHash);
=> f899139df5e1059396431415e770c6dd
```

I want the variable to be like the printf return, so that I can send scoreData to a web server:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, scoreData);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `snprintf()` to format the text into a character array:

```
char scoreData[128];

snprintf(scoreData, sizeof scoreData, "name=%s&score=%d&score_hash=%s\n",
         name, score, scoreHash);
```